# Adjusting Vertical and Horizontal Space between nodes in tikz flow chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I got the following flow chart diagram in tikz.
[image]

---

### **MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes, arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}


% Define block styles

\tikzstyle{block} = 
    [
        rectangle
      , draw
     % , fill=blue!20
      , text width=12.5em
      , text centered
      , node distance=1.5cm
      , rounded corners
      , minimum height=2em
      ]

\tikzstyle{block2} = 
    [
        rectangle
      , draw
     % , fill=blue!20
      , text width=6.5em
      , text centered
      , node distance=1.5cm
      , rounded corners
      , minimum height=2em
      ]

\tikzstyle{line} = 
    [
        draw
     , -latex'
     ]



\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm, auto]


  % Place nodes
    \node [block] (ZeroSlopes) {Test Slopes are equal to Zero, i.e.,\\ $\textrm{H}_{0}:\beta_{1}=\beta_{1}=\ldots=\beta_{t}=0$};
    \node [block, below left = 2.0cm and 0.1cm  of ZeroSlopes] (CommonSlopes) {Test Slopes are equal, i.e.,\\ $\textrm{H}_{0}:\beta_{1}=\beta_{1}=\ldots=\beta_{t}=\beta$};
    \node [block, below right = 2.0cm and 0.1cm   of ZeroSlopes] (ZeroSlope) {Fit Common  Slope \& Test Slope is equal to Zero, i.e.,\\ $\textrm{H}_{0}:\beta=0$};



    \node [block2, below left of=CommonSlopes, node distance=4.5cm] (UnequalSlopes) {Fit Unequal Slopes Model};
    \node [block2, below right of=CommonSlopes, node distance=4.5cm] (CommonSlope) {Fit a Common Slope Model};
    \node [block2, below left of=ZeroSlope, node distance=4.5cm] (ParallelLines) {Fit Parallel Lines Model};
    \node [block2, below right of=ZeroSlope, node distance=4.5cm] (ANOVA) {Fit ANOVA Model};


  % Draw edges
    \path[line] let \p1=(ZeroSlopes.south), \p2=(CommonSlopes.north) in (ZeroSlopes.south) --  +(0,0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) -| node [pos=0.3, above] {Reject} (CommonSlopes.north);
    \path[line] let \p1=(ZeroSlopes.south), \p2=(ZeroSlope.north) in (ZeroSlopes.south) -- +(0,0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) -| node [pos=0.3, above] {Retain} (ZeroSlope.north);

    \path[line] let \p1=(CommonSlopes.south), \p2=(UnequalSlopes.north) in (CommonSlopes.south) -- +(0,0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) -| node [pos=0.3, above] {Reject} (UnequalSlopes.north);
    \path[line] let \p1=(CommonSlopes.south), \p2=(CommonSlope.north) in (CommonSlopes.south) -- +(0,0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) -| node [pos=0.3, above] {Retain} (CommonSlope.north);

    \path[line] let \p1=(ZeroSlope.south), \p2=(ParallelLines.north) in (ZeroSlope.south) -- +(0,0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) -| node [pos=0.3, above] {Reject} (ParallelLines.north);
    \path[line] let \p1=(ZeroSlope.south), \p2=(ANOVA.north) in (ZeroSlope.south) -- +(0,0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) -| node [pos=0.3, above] {Retain} (ANOVA.north);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**Question**

---

I've problem with adjusting the horizontal and vertical distances between the nodes. You can see that the nodes horizontally are far apart from each other. Is there any better better approach to make flow charts with tikz? Any help to resolve the problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution proposes a matrix node scheme to draw the flow diagram. The horizontal and vertical distances between the nodes can be adjusted via `column sep` and `row sep`, respectively.

[image]

By adjusting `column sep` from -5m to -20mm, one gets

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = 
    [
        rectangle
      , draw
     %, fill=blue!20
      , text width=12.5em
      , text centered
     %, node distance=1.5cm
      , rounded corners
      , minimum height=2em
      ]

\tikzstyle{block2} = 
    [
        rectangle
      , draw
     %, fill=blue!20
      , text width=6.5em
      , text centered
     %, node distance=1.5cm
      , rounded corners
      , minimum height=2em
      ]

\tikzstyle{line} = 
    [
        draw
     , -latex'
     ]
\begin{tikzpicture}       % a 3 x 7 matrix
  \matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes, nodes=block, column sep=-5mm, row sep=1.5cm] 
{
& & &\node [block] (ZeroSlopes) {Test Slopes are equal to Zero, i.e.,\\ $\textrm{H}_{0}:\beta_{1}=\beta_{1}=\ldots= \beta_{t}=0$};  & & & \\ 
&\node [block] (CommonSlopes) {Test Slopes are equal, i.e.,\\ $\textrm{H}_{0}:\beta_{1}=\beta_{1}=\ldots
=\beta_{t}=\beta$};  & & & &
    \node [block] (ZeroSlope)  {Fit Common  Slope \& Test Slope is equal to Zero, i.e.,\\ $\textrm{H}_{0}:\beta=0$}; &     \\
\node [block2] (UnequalSlopes) {Fit Unequal Slopes Model};
&&
\node [block2] (CommonSlope)   {Fit a Common Slope Model};        
&&
\node [block2] (ParallelLines) {Fit Parallel Lines Model};
&&
\node [block2] (ANOVA) {Fit ANOVA Model};\\ 
};  
% Draw edges
\path[line] (ZeroSlopes.south)    --+(0,-0.5) -| node [pos=0.3, above] {Reject} (CommonSlopes.north);
\path[line] (ZeroSlopes.south)   -- +(0,-0.5) -| node [pos=0.3, above] {Retain} (ZeroSlope.north);
%
\path[line] (CommonSlopes.south) -- +(0,-0.8) -| node [pos=0.3, above] {Reject} (UnequalSlopes.north);
\path[line] (CommonSlopes.south) -- +(0,-0.8) -| node [pos=0.3, above] {Retain} (CommonSlope.north);
%
\path[line] (ZeroSlope.south)    -- +(0,-0.8) -| node [pos=0.3, above] {Reject} (ParallelLines.north);
\path[line] (ZeroSlope.south)    -- +(0,-0.8) -| node [pos=0.3, above] {Retain} (ANOVA.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jesse for your answer. I'll keep the question open and will see if have another solution. Thanks for your efforts and help.

Comment: @MYaseen208 -- Please do.