# Flow chart diverging and converging arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

**Question:**
I am struggling to split the arrows in the flow chart. I have tried looking at similar code but cannot seem to reproduce it. *How can I get the ideal output?*

**Relevant Research:**

- [Diverging arrows, tikz/pgf - flowchart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306748/diverging-arrows-tikz-pgf-flowchart/306752)
- [Adjusting Vertical and Horizontal Space between nodes in tikz flow
  chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154743/adjusting-vertical-and-horizontal-space-between-nodes-in-tikz-flow-chart)
- [Converging and diverging nodes in a flowchart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121665/converging-and-diverging-nodes-in-a-flowchart)

**MWE:**

```
\begin{document}


\begin{center}

    % Define block styles
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
        text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
        text width=4.5cm, text badly centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em, minimum width=5cm]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    % \tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em]



    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2.5cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block, below of=dav] (install)           {Install fan, heat sink, thermal dough and 4 jumpers on the board};
    \node [block, below of=install] (voltage)       {Complete Voltage Testing};
    \node [block, below of=voltage] (recordvalue)   {Record serial number Voltage Testing is a pass or fail to spreadsheet};
    \node [block, below left  of=recordvalue, node distance=6.5cm] (flashTX) {Flash as Tx};
    \node [block, below right of=recordvalue, node distance=6.5cm] (flashRX) {Flash as Rx};
    \node [block, below of=flashTX] (testflashTX)   {Test Tx with \textit{Golden Rx}};
    \node [block, below of=flashRX] (testflashRX)   {Test Rx with \textit{Golden Tx}};     
    
    \node [decision, below of=recordvalue, node distance=10cm] (passfail)   {Pass/Fail}; 
    

    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (dav) -- (install);
    \path [line] (install) -- (voltage);
    \path [line] (voltage) -- (recordvalue);
    \path [line] (recordvalue) |- (flashTX);
    \path [line] (recordvalue) |- (flashRX);


    \path [line] (flashTX) -- (testflashTX);
    \path [line] (flashRX) -- (testflashRX);
      

\end{document}
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Ideal Output:**

[image]

Comment: Please, make your code fragment complete and compilabe! Undefined shape  `dav` , missed libraries, etc.

Comment: Also shoved image are not produced with your code ... missed are some blocks ...

Comment: Thank you for showing your research in the question, also well-formatted. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
In diagram are added new nodes as you require in edited question.

In MWE (Minimal Working Example) below are in comparison to your code fragment done the changes:

- nodes are organised in three chains (using TikZ library `chains`) where is for positioning of nodes used `positioning` library and its syntax (by this distances between nodes are equal in determined by `node distance = <below> and <right>`)
- nodes in chains are linked by arrows drawn by instruction `join` defined in the `chains` package
- connections between nodes are discontinued in four places by use of code `suspend join`
- connections between nodes, which are not considered in `join`, are drawn separately

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  node distance = 4mm and 2mm,
    start chain = A going below,
     arr/.style = {-Stealth},
    base/.style = {draw, fill=blue!30, font=\small,
                   text width=42mm, minimum height=8mm,
                   align=center},
   block/.style = {base, rounded corners},
decision/.style = {base, diamond,  aspect=1.6, 
                   text width=21mm, inner xsep=0pt},
suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}
        }
\makeatother
% Place nodes
% main branch
    \begin{scope}[nodes={block, on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\node   {Get Dante AV board from batch};            % name: A-1
\node   {Install fan, heat sink, 
         thermal dough and 4 jumpers on the board};  
\node   {Complete Voltage Testing};
\node   {Record serial number Voltage Testing 
         is a pass or fail to spreadsheet};         % name: A-4
    \end{scope}
\coordinate[below=of A-4] (aux1);
    \begin{scope}[nodes={block, on chain=A, join=by arr}]
% first left branch
% here had to be discontinued "join" instruction from main branch
\node [suspend join,                         % name: A-5
       below  left=of aux1 -| A-4.west] {Flash as Tx};
\node                                   {Test Tx with \textit{Golden Rx}};
% first right branch
% here had to be discontinued "join" instruction from main branch again
\node [suspend join,                         % name; A-7
       below right=of aux1 -| A-4.east] {Flash as Rx};
\node                                   {Test Rx with \textit{Golden Tx}};
    \end{scope}
% decision
\coordinate[below=of A-6.south -| aux1] (aux2);   
\node [decision, below=of aux2] (decision)      {Pass/Fail};
% end branches
    \begin{scope}[nodes={block, on chain=A, join=by arr}]
% left end branch
% here had to be discontinued "join" instruction from main branch again
\node [suspend join,                          
       below=of decision -| A-6]    {Flash P};  % name A-9
\node                               {Test T};
\node                               {Record};
% right end branch
% here had to be discontinued "join" instruction from left end branch
\node [suspend join,                          
       below=of decision -| A-8]    {Flash F};  % name A-12
\node                               {Test T};
    \end{scope}
% Draw edges which are not considered in join
% left
\draw[arr]  (A-4) -- (aux1) -| (A-5);
\draw[arr]  (A-6) |- (aux2) -- (decision);
\draw[arr]  (decision) -| (A-9)     node[pos=0.25,above] {Pass};
% right
\draw[arr]  (aux1) -| (A-7);
\draw       (A-8) |- (aux2);
\draw[arr]  (decision) -| (A-12)    node[pos=0.25,above] {Fail};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produce:

[image]

Is this what you after?

Comment: thank you so much, I was pretty naïve to guess I could continue on by myself after this point, but I really struggled to complete what I had in mind. I've put the final flow chart in the question -...

Comment: @3kstc, all what you need is to form new end branches in `scope`  to which you add new nodes. See edited answer.